# how to fix Excel VLookup return #ref! with Indirect + concatenation function to build a file path

Tags: excel, vlookup

I try to isolate each part of my excel function and can't find the solution for now.
I'm using in a same row 3 functions

1. Vlookup (search value from a specific column based on a reference/ID)
2. Concatenate (building a file path from a tab which can be dynamic)
3. Indirect (turning the concatenation into a text input)

I've a file located in my computer such as

- Path:desktop/folder A/
- File names: data_fr.xls (for French and a second file data_en.xls for English product data in French or English but same product ID).

content on the data_fr an an exemple

|  | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 | 1 | John |
| row 2 | 2 | Tintin |

Those path and file names are saved in a separate excel file named test.xls and tab called "dynamic".

| language | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| French | desktop/folder A/ | data_fr.xls |
| English | desktop/folder A/ | data_en.xls |

from my new tab called "trial" of the test.xls excel file I want to collect the information from the file data_fr, tab content, data from product ID 1 (as an exemple).

if the vlookup works like a charm with the direct path, it is not working as soon as I want to create the path using indirect function

```
=vlookup(1,'desktop/folder A/[data_fr.xls]content'!$A:$B,2,false)
return:John
```

but by doing this it does not work and I don't know why.

```
=vlookup(A1,indirect(concatenate("'",'dynamic'!B$2,"[",'dynamic'!C$2,"]content'!$A:$B")),1,false)
```

return: #ref!

I've isolated the concatenation function and it works but as soon as I'm adding the indirect function it is broken. Some things is missing.

What do you have in mind which could help me?
FYI: I'm using a Mac, and the files are both opens.

I try the basic vlookup and works, isolated the concatenate function to build the path and the path looks accurate.
As soon as I'm adding the indirect function, it returns an error and don't know why.

Regards,
Henri

Comment: The file must be open if you use INDIRECT.

Comment: you are right, indirect require to have the file open. but in all my trial my files were all opens.

Comment: For some reason, the excel code worked fine this morning! So I might have dome something last Friday which did solve everything. I've used different source to solve my issue https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1110218-file-path-concatenate.html, and https://exceljet.net/functions/indirect-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now working today and to be honest I don't know very much what happened.

Two links helped me to solve my issue

- https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1110218-file-path-concatenate.html
- https://exceljet.net/functions/indirect-function

I rebuilt this morning anyway my function
with file Path , file name, concatenate Path & file, indirect and to finish vlookup.

```
VLOOKUP("datatosearch",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",F4,"[",G4,"]Generic tab'!$B2:$AC14")),4,FALSE)
```

Job done.

Thanks